# it is possible to disable some of input buttons in android input

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

I want to disable some of buttons in typed area. 
for example I want to disable 1,2,3 buttons in keyboard.
I want to learn is it possible or not?

[image]

Comment: you can override the event related to that button, for example [overriding back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity)

Comment: How can I override keyboard input type?

Comment: 1. [Handling Keyboard Actions](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html)  and 2. [Overriding Android Native Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758751/overriding-android-native-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in your xml

```
<EditText 
  android:inputType="text" 
  android:digits="0,4,5,6,7,8,9
/>
```

Comment: Still I can click the other buttons I want to see them disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code either on java side

```
private List<Char> allowedChars = new ArrayList(Char);
allowedChars.add(...);
allowedChars.add(...);
allowedChars.add(...);
allowedChars.add(...);
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                        // Your condition here 
                        if (!allowedChars.contains(source.charAt(i)))) { 
                                return ""; 
                        } 
                } 
                return null; 
        } 
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```